# Lubuntu: Using .sh script as a keybind, code works, executing script gives errors

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, key-bindings

This is my first ever post on stackoverflow, hope I don't break any rules. I'm a complete Linux newbie (installed Lubuntu 14.04 64bit last night) so be duly warned.

In short, I'm trying to get my laptop touchpad toggle to work (Fn+F3 on my Inspiron5110). I have a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $(synclient -l | grep TouchpadOff | awk '{print $3}') == 1 ] ; then
synclient touchpadoff=0;
else
synclient touchpadoff=1;
fi
```

I got it from http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=10996 . If I paste the script code in the terminal and execute it, it works (touchpad goes on/off). However, I want to bind it to a key so in my lubuntu-rc.xml I've added the following:

```
<!-- disable touchpad -->
    <keybind key="XF86TouchpadToggle">
      <action name="Execute">
        <command>/usr/local/bin/touchpad.sh</command>
      </action>
    </keybind>
```

When I press the necessary key combo however I get `"Failure to execute child process "/usr/local/bin/touchpad.sh" (No such file or directory)"`. However I can see in this directory, both in the file manager and when I use `ls` in the terminal that the file is there:

```
/usr/local/bin$ ls -l
total 4
-rwxrwxr-x 1 paspaldzhiev paspaldzhiev 145 юни  2 22:54 touchpad.sh
```

I used `chmod +x touchpad.sh` to make it executable.

Now, where this gets even more confusing:

If I use `bash /usr/local/bin/touchpad.sh` I get:

```
paspaldzhiev@areuexperienced:/usr/local/bin$ bash touchpad.sh
touchpad.sh: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
touchpad.sh: line 6: `fi'
```

Though as I've said above I know for a fact that the code works if I just paste it in the terminal.

Further, if I use `./touchpad.sh` I get :

```
paspaldzhiev@areuexperienced:/usr/local/bin$ ./touchpad.sh
bash: ./touchpad.sh: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Just to note that I'm not very sure what the difference between `bash touchpad.sh` and `./touchpad.sh` is in terms of execution, it's just that my more Linux-savvy friends told me to try these :D.

In any case, I have no idea how to proceed henceforth, could anyone please shed a light on what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Something looks weird with the following: 
`/bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`.
Make sure you dont have any weird escape characters on that line. The /bin/bash binary doesnt have a ^M suffix

Comment: The ^M in your last error msg is your big hint ; -). Somehow you have used a windows editor, file transfer or something. Try `dos2unix touchpad.sh`. It will remove all the CR (^M) chars from end of lines. It should work then. Good luck.

Comment: That worked! I don't really remember but I used either Leafpad or SublimeText3, both on my Lubuntu. Anyway, problem solved, thank you!!! Just to avoid this problem again, what would you recommend I use for writing .sh files?

Comment: Most editors have a 'Unix' file mode. Look around for that. The standard Unix editor is 'vi', but it has a steepish learning curve, so unless you're making a real commitment to Unix scripting/programming stick with what you know and learn the options avaiable in the tools you already know. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

The ^M in your last error msg is your big hint ; -). Somehow you have used a windows editor, file transfer or something. Try `dos2unix touchpad.sh`. It will remove all the CR (^M) chars from end of lines. It should work then. Good luck. –  shellter

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for script, since there is no need for `if` instruction.

Place this piece of code in your lubuntu-rc.xml

```
<keybind key="XF86TouchpadToggle">
  <action name="Execute">
    <command>synclient TouchpadOff=$((1-$(synclient | grep TouchpadOff | awk '{print $3}')))</command>
  </action>
</keybind>
```